# Cant Validate RSS Feed on wordpress site

Tags: xml, wordpress, parsing, rss, feed

Really struggling with trying to validate RSS Feed on my wordpress site

When i run it through Feed Validator i get this error

XML parsing error: :45:0: junk after document element

can anyone shed some light as to whats going on please??

you can see the full error here

[Scotlands Route 66](https://validator.w3.org/feed/check.cgi?url=https%3A%2F%2Fscotlandsroute66.co.uk%2Ffeed%2F)

i have tried to locate where this is pulling from but its all double dutch to me

Comment: I used Visual Studio to read file.  I found to issues 1) The webpage does not support HTTPS (secure) and had to change URL to HTTP. 2) The first rss feed is good.  There are extra data after the first rss feed that is incomplete.  There is text at the end of the file starting with <pre> that is causing the issue.